Built Keycloak Environment, but Unable to login to Keycloak Server
I am learning Keycloak by following this Pluralsight course.
I've created one folder and created docker-compose.yml file inside this folder with the below code.
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  keyCloak:
    image: bitnami/keycloak
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES_DB
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - keycloak_data:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data
      - keycloak_config:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration
volumes:
  keycloak_data:
  keycloak_config:
  postgres_data:


I have executed http://my-computer:8080/ URL in the browser. Then, I was presented with Keycloak login window. I've tried to use Keycloak as username, and password  as password. Then, I am getting the below screen.

I was unable to find resolution for this issue. Looks like cookies are enabled by default in the latest version of Chorme browser. I'm getting almost the same issue in Firefox browser as well. Can someone please help to to resolve this error!

Check out this similar question and comments/answers: Why after login keycloak display "Cookie not found. Please make sure cookies are enabled in your browser."
Also, according to your docker-compose file (KEYCLOAK_USER=admin, KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin), you should login Keycloak admin console with admin as username and admin as password, not keycloak and password as you mentioned.
